# Unit Testing Object Box for Flutter App in macOS is failing

Tags: flutter, flutter-objectbox

While reading from object box for doing unit testing for flutter app in mac, it is giving error like

`RangeError (byteOffset): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

It is coming for any call of `query.find()`. Object box version is 1.6.2

How to get around this ?

Edit code for reproducibility

```
final query = _box.query(any query).build(); 
final data = query.find(); 
query.close(); 
return data;
```

Comment: Please, show us the code that leads you to this error

Comment: Any query method will fail

```
 final query = _box
        .query(any query)
        .build();

    final data = query.find();
    query.close();
    return data;
```

Added code above in proper format